# Semi complicated custom taxonomy question

Tags: customization, taxonomy

Given the following the following products:

product 1

- Naam
- part of taxonomy "brand" value "Joolz"
- part of taxonomy "Categorie" value "Chair"

product 2

- Naam
- part of taxonomy "brand" value "Joolz"
- part of taxonomy "Categorie" value "Car"

product 3

- Naam
- part of taxonomy "brand" value "Costa"
- part of taxonomy "Categorie" value "Bike"

How could I want to retrieve all the categorie value that has products related to them with a given Brand, So I give value "Costa" I get bike, if i give value "Joolz" i get "chair" and "car"

Comment: Bram, I'm sure I just did something similar to what you are requesting but I think your question needs a little more clarification. Precisely, why would brand "Joolz" give you both a chair and bike? From your example above product 1 and 2 appear to be the same. Please offer more information. Thnx.

Comment: oh sorry wrong example's edited, would appreciate it a ton if you could share what you made, if its indeed what I need.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand what you are asking. You have two different taxonomies: "Brand" and "Categorie". On any given product, both taxonomies exist. What you would like to do is to return the available "Categorie" taxonomies for any product that has a specific "Brand" taxonomy. As your example states, you only want to know what categorie are assigned to Products with a brand of "Joolz". Is that correct?

Comment: Yea I want all the categorie taxonomy terms that has products with the brand Joolz. Lets say I have 1000 products with different brands and categories. Now I want to be able to pull all the categories that a certain brand has product for. So I can make a brand template page that for example says : 'Overview for all Joolz chairs, Joolz cars etc', but if Joolz doesnt make Bikes and hence has no producs in the car categorie I dont want to echo it. I want to create an array that has all the categorie name a brand has products in so I can loop thru it and echo it with the brand term in front of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with a [`tax_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) to get posts with the `'categorie'` taxonomy term you want. Assuming a custom query:

```
$tax_query_args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'categorie',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'costa' )
        ),
);
$tax_query = new WP_Query( $tax_query_args );
```

Then, step through that query, and use [`get_the_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) to return the `brand` taxonomy terms for each post, and add them to an array:

```
$tax_query_brand_terms = array();

if ( $tax_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $tax_query->have_posts() ) : $tax_query->the_post();

    $post_brand_terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'brand' );
    if ( is_array( $post_brand_terms ) ) {
        $tax_query_brand_terms = array_merge( $tax_query_brand_terms, $post_brand_terms );
    }

endwhile; endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Now, the `$tax_query_brand_terms` array should be populated with all of the `brand` taxonomy terms for posts in the specified `categorie` taxonomy term.

If you want to wrap it in a function, allowing you to pass a `categorie` taxonomy term as a parameter:

```
function wpse63233_tax_query_brand_terms( $categorie = false ) {
    if ( false == $catgorie ) {
        return false;
    }
    // Also, put in some error checking here,
    // e.g. comparing $categorie against
    // get_terms( 'categorie' )

    // Query 'categorie' posts
    $tax_query_args = array(
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'categorie',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array( $categorie )
            ),
    );
    $tax_query = new WP_Query( $tax_query_args );

    // Get 'brand' terms from all returned posts
    $tax_query_brand_terms = array();

    if ( $tax_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $tax_query->have_posts() ) : $tax_query->the_post();

        $post_brand_terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'brand' );
        if ( is_array( $post_brand_terms ) ) {
            $tax_query_brand_terms = array_merge( $tax_query_brand_terms, $post_brand_terms );
        }

    endwhile; endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();

    // Return the array
    return $tax_query_brand_terms;
}
```

Comment: Shouldnt the array ('costa') be the variable and categorie fixed? I want to place this in a brand template so it gets the brand of the specific page and then looks up all the associated categories

Comment: Yes, sorry; I forgot to add the variable to the query args. Updated/fixed now.

Comment: Changed categorie and brand to what its in my database, (pa_subcategorie and pa_merk) added echo of the function in merk taxonomy template while passing it a brand i know exist and is present in different subcategories

so echo wpse63233_tax_query_brand_terms( 'Joolz' )

And doesnt return anything, I know I should be looping thru the array but normally this way should at least echo array, but it echoes nothing

Comment: What do you get from `var_dump( $tax_query)`?

Comment: i do 
$value =  wpse63233_tax_query_brand_terms( 'joolz' )
echo joolz[0] 
This shoudl at least echo an array not?

Comment: Inside the function, after you define `$tax_query = new WP_Query( $tax_query_args )`, add this: `var_dump( $tax_query );`. **What does this output**?

Comment: ),
    ));
    $tax_query = new WP_Query( $tax_query_args );
 var_dump( $tax_query );

    // Get 'brand' terms from all returned posts
    $tax_query_brand_terms = array();

like this? Still no return

Comment: I'm using custom post types, this shouldnt matter tho right?

Comment: "*like this? Still no return*" You should get at least a `null` returned. You'll see the output wherever you *call* the function. "*I'm using custom post types, this shouldnt matter tho right?*" **Incorrect**. That **very much** matters. The default query args expect the `post` post-type. If you want to query a *different* post-type, you need to indicate it via `'post_type' => {posttype}` in your `$tax_query_args` array.

Comment: Ok thanks for all the help, ill try further tomorrow, I should be able to get it to work. Sorry for my noobiness.